# флаги, ключи, параметры в скриптах bash

Tags: linux, bash, скрипт, параметры

Как можно сделать флаги в bash по типу --delay 3737, -a 6, -o?

Comment: Какую проблему вы пытаетесь решить? Приведите пример кода.

Comment: и, по традиции: [How do I parse command line arguments in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/192249/4827341)